# sklearn : missing pruning for decision trees

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-trees

Why pruning is not currently supported in scikit-learn? How can we tune the decision trees to make a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something which is [planned](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6557) to be done. Setting the minimum number of samples required at a leaf node or a split as well as setting the maximum depth of the tree are how you want to work around this.

Answer (score 2):

I have performed Cost Complexity Pruning Algorithm on Sklearn's CART(Classification) model,

I have performed Error Complexity Pruning Algorithm on Sklearn's CART(Regression) model.

It is available [here](https://github.com/appleyuchi/Decision_Tree_Prune).

A relevant issue for sklearn about your question is [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6557).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the 0.22 dev version of sklearn. Looks like tree pruning will be implemented in the next version.

https://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new.html section sklearn.tree